# A question on length of some module over Noetherian local ring

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, modules

I am trying to understand a proof of theorem $14.14$ in Matsumura Commutative ring theory book.

Let $(A,\mathfrak m, k)$ be a Noetherian local ring and $\mathfrak q$ be an $\mathfrak m$-primary ideal. Let $x$ be an indeterminate over $A$. $S=A[x]-\mathfrak m[x]$. Denote $A(x)=A[x]_S$. Then $A(x)/\mathfrak mA(x)$ is the quotient field of $k[x]$. I need to show that

> $l_A(A/\mathfrak q^n)=l_{A(x)}(A(x)/\mathfrak q^nA(x))$.

As a hint the book says that :

Since $A(x)$ is flat over $A$ then for any two ideals $I\supset I'$, with $I/I'\cong k$,

$$IA(x)/I'A(x)\cong (I/I')\otimes_A A(x)\cong k\otimes A(x)\cong A(x)/\mathfrak mA(x).$$

I tried using the hint in the following way:

For $I/\mathfrak q^n\supsetneq I'/\mathfrak q^n$, with $I/\mathfrak q^n/I'/\mathfrak q^n$ is simple implies $I/I'\cong k$ and hence $(IA(x)/\mathfrak q^nA(x))/(I'A(x)/\mathfrak q^nA(x))$ is also simple using the hint so that the two lengths become equal.

I am not so sure about the above argument. My question is if the above argument is right or can anyone help me to show the above equality.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This sounds right.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a question asking about some length formula few days ago. Did you delete it?